# How setup WiFi proxy in Android 9?

Tags: settings, proxy

I need to setup a WiFi proxy on Android 9  but it seems they removed the feature , all tutorials I found refers to old versions of Android.

Answer (score 12):

The wifi proxy settings are still configured under the advanced options for your wifi network.

The reason you can't find them is just bad Android UX. They're in a scrollable area that doesn't look scrollable (it looks like it just says 'metered'). If you try scrolling down in the wifi settings window you'll see it immediately.

Comment: Wow thanks! I would never be able to find it without your help! Can't believe how bad the UX is!

Comment: Someone at Google needs to be kicked for this. Searching for something like this for an hour.

Answer (score 3):

I found you can't edit proxy of an existing WiFi profile anymore, I dunno why they removed the feature.
But you can just remove your saved Wifi profile and add a new, then you will easily find proxy options under advanced drop down.

Answer (score 2):

click on the pencil to edit network details. A popup appears to change your wifi password, and it doesn't look scrollable but if you scroll you'll see the advanced options and Proxy Settings. Horrible UI design